# iOS - Check if iTunes Radio is playing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, itunes, mpmusicplayercontroller

I am trying to avoid having multiple audio sources playing at the same time while the user is using my app.

I am checking if the music is playing by using 
(MPMusicPlayerController *)iPodMusicPlayer
ref :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MPMusicPlayerController/iPodMusicPlayer

But apparently it does not check if the Apple iTunes radio is playing.
The iTunes radio app is only available for US apple accounts.

Is there a way to check if audio is playing with the iTunes Radio ?